# Sorting Numbers in Sharepoint

Tags: 2013, list, ordering

How can I sort a list using a field that has a number format like this:

```
1.1
1.1.1
2
2.1
.
.
.
10.1
10.2
```

I have to use the field as a string to can handle as many sublevels the user wants, but then i get the sort like this:

```
1
1.1
1.1.1
10.1
10.2
2
2.1
.
.
.
```

And that's not what i'm looking for

Comment: This question seems to have been answered in the past, see here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/sort-order-issue

Comment: Yes, i was looking for a workaround because adding 0s to the beginning of the numbers is kind of odd

Answer (score 1):

Workaround

1. Create a calculated field which removes the . character from that field. Except the first dot. i.e 1,1.1,1.11,1.12 etc.
2. Convert that to a number
3. Sort on that field.

You can hide that field from the view.

```
Actual Field        Calculated Field 
------------        ----------------
1                   1
1.1                 1.1
1.1.1               1.11
1.1.1.1             1.111
2                   2
2.1                 2.1
2.1.1               2.11
2.1.1.1             2.111
..
```

If you sort calculated field it will always sort in proper Numeric Order.

Comment: the problem with this is that only will work for two levels, what happen if the user add a third level like 1.1.1 or a fourth level?

Comment: It's not a decimal, every point it's like a sublevel --> 1 . 1 . 1 <--- that has 3 levels...

Comment: I couldn't use a calculated column if the field has more than 4 levels with your solution, also I couldn't sort by that field even when that calculated column returned a number. I tried to add "+ 0 " at the end of the formula but i still got problems sorting

Comment: I cannot use a SP2013 workflow and in 2010 i have no the Replace function for strings