# List items arrange

Tags: list, list-item

I have a list where when I Arrange List Ascending, it uses the first number instead of the whole number?

[image: How do I change this?]

Comment: Answered at [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/sort-order-issue) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138750/sorting-numbers-in-sharepoint).

Comment: i found a solution by typing 0 in front of the numbers and that makes it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess "Maskine" column is text based column and ordering with string order. Change column type to numeric and it will order just what you want to.

Edit: If the list is big, I recommend you to create a calculated column with the numeric return value with the following rule. If you try to order by this calculated column it should order the right way.

```
 =INT(Title)
```

Comment: Its the title field that has been renamed "Maskine" so it is quite a big change if the hole list should be changed.

Comment: If the list is big, I recommend you to create a calculated column with the numeric return value with the rule that updated answer. If you try to order by this calculated column it should order the right way.