# Version field sort order not working properly

Tags: 2013, document-library, versioning, ootb

**The problem**

I have a document library with versioning, and I am tweaking the view through the UI.

It appears that, right ootb, when we sort by `Version` it doesn't really sort properly, as it appears to consider `"11"` like a string and not like the interger `11`.

Sounds overkill if I am to create a new, calculated column just for this.

From the query string, I can see that the field being sorted is `_UIVersionString` so I guess I shouldn't be surprised.

```
SortField=_UIVersionString-SortDir=Asc
```

Anyone else experienced this and has any tips?

**Similar threads**

[Sort order issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/sort-order-issue)

[How can I add the UIVersion (integer) field to a view?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c23790cb-6fb3-41bb-90b8-26cdbd08e289/how-can-i-add-the-uiversion-integer-field-to-a-view?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)

**Screenshot**

[image: version ordering]

**Update**

I might just be able to update the view through CSOM to make it use "UI Version" field instead of "Version" (Title Name)

[image]

Comment: Did you try _UIVersion field?

Comment: it works if I change the URL manually but how I would I add this field to the view?

Comment: I think it is not possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much to my dissatisfaction, the cleanliest solution I could find was to create a new calculated column, retrieving the `integer` value of the `Version` field.

**Create a new calculated column using the formula**

```
=VALUE(Version)
```

e.g.

[image]

Apparently, the `Version` field - also known by it's StaticName `_UIVersionString` - is of type `Text/String`, therefore cannot be sorted properly.

There is a field `_UIVersion` that can in fact be used to sort by version perfectly, however the **contents** of this field are in a different format, as shown below (something like 512 for each major version). These hidden fields can be added by tweaking the view with CSOM for example.

[image]

A quick "workaround" for getting this (manually) would be to replace `_UIVersionString` in the URL by `_UIVersion` and use `Asc` or `Desc` for sorting order.

SortField%3D**_UIVersion**-SortDir%3D**Asc**